# Circle animation on complete view controller

Tags: objective-c, animation, design-patterns, core-graphics, geometry

How to show the time with animation of circle line, when time is change the small circle line are rotating and make a digit to show the time.
I have done these functionality and get the circles with rotating line but, in my approach i have use the UIView to show the circle and two another view inside the circle view to show the two circle line, and then i am rotating these circle line view with transformation to make the number.
I have successfully get the time with animating circle line but the main problem is app is too slow. I have created a lot view in view controller that take too much time to handle these view. 
This is the screenshot of my page.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swrlq.png)

Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Interesting idea. Did you try to implement it with a single view, just drawing circles in it using Core Graphics? (for instance using `UIBezierPath`)? Maybe it would be less performance issues, because a lot of views can be heavy to handle